# Setting a default value when getting XML values via Linq

Tags: c#, group-by, linq-to-xml

I’m using Linq to extract values from some XML. Shown below is a simplified example to show the problem I’m having. The following code works fine on the XML shown below. The problem I have is when the `groupBy` section is missing. Because when it’s missing `Data.Element("groupBy").Element("property)` fails because `Data.Element("groupBy")` will be null. Is it possible to modify my Linq statement to allow it to provide a default or should it be approached in a different way?

```
var e = (from Data in theXML.Descendants("exportFile")
 select new Export
 {    
     OutputFileName = Data.Element("outputFileName") != null ? (string)Data.Element("outputFileName") : "",
     GroupByProperty =  Data.Element("groupBy").Element("property") != null ? (string)Data.Element("groupBy").Element("property") : ""
 }).First();
```

---

```
<exportFile>
    <outputFileName>output.xml</outputFileName>
    <groupBy>
        <property>DeviceId</property>
    </groupBy>
</exportFile>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can already make it slightly nicer than it is using the null coalescing operator. However, to cope with the `groupby` element being missing is harder:

```
select new Export
{    
    OutputFileName = (string) Data.Element("outputFileName") ?? "",
    GroupByProperty = Data.Element("groupBy") == null ? ""
           : (string) Data.Element("groupBy").Element("property") ?? ""
}).First();
```

The conversion to string just returns null if the element reference is null.

An alternative would be:

```
GroupByProperty = 
    (string) Data.Elements("groupBy").Elements("property").FirstOrDefault() ?? ""
```

That uses the extension method which allows you to call `Elements` on an `IEnumerable<XElement>`... so that will (lazily) evaluate a sequence of every `property` element under a `groupBy` element under `Data`, then take the first of them if any exist, then apply the string conversion.

Comment: I think the OP was saying the groupBy element did not exist in the XML. Wouldn't this still fail if that was the case?

Comment: Interesting. I didn't realize that you could use FirstOrDefault() when you had a null value upstream in the call chain. Learn something new every day.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply add an additional check in the statement (and clean things up a bit using the null coalescing operator):

```
GroupByProperty = Data.Element("groupBy") != null ? 
    (Data.Element("groupBy").Element("property") ?? "") : "";
```